# Do-while being skipped over or If statement not working

Tags: c

After running through the two functions once, the `do while` loop keeps skipping over to the `while` condition and goes straight to the getInt function, which then gets stuck in the 
`scanf("%d,%c", &Value, &NL)`
until a character (or word like office) is inputted. This will happen another 3 times, until the fourth "invalid INTEGER" message, which the "OUT OF RANGE" message will then show, only for the who process to happen all over again. Not sure if it's the `do-while` loop which is not working, or if the `if statements` are not functioning.

When testing the function(s) with a word (i.e. office) it `getInt` will declare the values an "invalid INTEGER", and when testing with the values 99 or 501, `getIntInRange` should declare the value "OUT OF RANGE", however, the function `getIntInRange` will only show "OUT OF RANGE" message after 5 iterations (if alternating between a value and character, the "OUT OF RANGE" message will display after the fourth attempt of inputting a value

```
// getInt function definition goes here:
int getInt(void) {
    int Value = 0;
    char NL = "";

    do {
        scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL);
        if (NL != '\n') {
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
        } else {
        };
    } while (NL != '\n');

    return Value;
}

// getIntInRange function definition goes here:
int getIntInRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    do {
        //getInt();
        if (getInt() < lowerBound | getInt() > upperBound) {
            printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between %d and %d>: ", lowerBound, upperBound);
        } else {
            continue;
        };
    } while (getInt() < lowerBound | getInt() > upperBound);

    return getInt();
}
```

My `getIntInRange` function is suppose to receive a value from the `getInt` function (`getInt` checks if the value entered is an integer) and compares the values with the lowerBound (set as 100 in a different source code) and the upperBound (set as 500 in a different source code). If the value is out of the range, then an error message will be displayed.

Comment: `if (getInt() < lowerBound | getInt() > upperBound) {` <- this is getting two ints. `while (getInt() < lowerBound | getInt() > upperBound);` <- and so is this. Making a total of 4 ints gotten per loop.

Comment: `(NL != '\n')` also appears in two places and can't possibly work

Comment: Text says `"%d,%c"`, code has `"%d%c"`.  Which one is true?  Post exact sample input.

Comment: `char NL = "";` is completely wrong and your compiler is telling you that. Just use `char NL;`. Than provide a [mcve] when asking questions. Save `getInt()` result to a variable and check that.

Comment: i guess you need to do `getInt()` only once. Store it in a variable and then, check the boundaries. And also put in the result you expect, in the question

Comment: There is a big difference between logical-OR (`||`) and bitwise-OR (`|`).  You _should_ be using logical-OR when you are performing logic.  Only use bitwise operators when you are manipulating bits.  But it doesn't affect the operation in this particular case (well it does, but it just means your broken program might exhibit a different broken output)

Comment: @Error_303: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple errors:

- `char NL = "";` is incorrect: `char` is a character, `""` is a string.
- `scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL);` is not a way to reliably test for correct input, you should instead test the return value of `scanf()`: `if (scanf("%d", &Value) != 1) { /* invalid input */ }`
- you should not call `getInt()` multiple times, the value must be stored into a variable and the variable should be tested, otherwise the value input is lost.
- you should consume the offending input before calling `scanf()` again.
- you should check for end of file to avoid an infinite loop.
- you should use `||` or `&&` for logical tests, `|` is for bit manipulations.
- avoid `do` / `while` loops, they are notoriously confusing and prone to programming errors.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int clearInput(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int getInt(void) {
    int value = 0;

    while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
         if (clearInput() == EOF) {
             printf("unexpected end of file\n");
             exit(1);
         }
         printf("not an integer, try again\n");
    }
    return value;
}

int getIntInRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    for (;;) {
        int value = getInt();
        if (value >= lowerBound && value <= upperBound)
            return value;
        printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between %d and %d>: ", lowerBound, upperBound);
    }
}
```